# Override Joomla article

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I seem to be able to override everything except an article. For example, I have placed **com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default_item.php** in **{mytemplate}/html/com_content/featured/default_item.php**, and changes I make to it are seen in the site. Similarly with various other overrides such as category displays etc. I see in the [official doc](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) it's the same for an article, but no matter what I do the changes I make to the overridden version just don't appear. When I make changes to the core article's default.php as a test, the changes are reflected instantly.

For the article, I copied **com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php** to **{mytemplate}/html/com_content/article/default.php**

Is there something different about overriding articles?

This is Joomla 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the **Template Manager** to create your overrides, this is the best 
way to create an override for the majority of the cases.

- See the step by step in:
  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

Create your override in: 
Column **Components** > **com_content** > **article**

Find your files in:
**your_site/templates/your_template/html/com_content/article/default.php**

Regards.

Comment: Irrespective of how you create the overrides, how do you do it for an article?

Comment: Follow the step by step in the article and create your override for articles in the Column Components > com_content > article

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Articles really are different. You need to go the Options tab of the article and at the bottom check the "Alternative Layout" setting. If you create an override as described, and call the file "foo.php", you **must** specify it here (there will be a new entry, "---From custom template--- foo"), as opposed to "Use Global", the default, or it will not appear no matter how you overwrite files in the html/... folder.